# How to add a colon to front of each string in array php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, regex, pdo

I am writing a PDO loop to create a number of MySQL statement.
PDO formating requires a colon in front of its column names.

before:

```
(cryptokeys, domains, records)
```

after:

```
(:cryptokeys, :domains, :records)
```

what php function can I use to put a colon in the front of each element in a foreach loop?

Comment: Where do you get this string from? Cannot you generate it properly in the very first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through array and simply add `:`

```
foreach ($array as &$value)
    $value = ':'.$value;
```

Also [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) can be used as well

```
array_walk($array, function(&$value) { $value = ':'.$value; });
```

Comment: It says I have to wait 9 min to check 'answer'. I won't forget. I figured it was easy like that, was just hitting a brain fart. And being PDO I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something ignorant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a inbuilt function called array_map that will help you with this

```
<?php

function fudge($s)
{
    return( ':' . $s);
}

$a = ('cryptokeys', 'domains', 'records');
$b = array_map("fudge", $a);
print_r($b);
?>
```